# I can't import MySQLdb to my Python Program

Tags: python, mysql, macos, mysql-python

I need to use a MySQL Database in my Python program, so i need to connect Python to MySQL.

I am using MacOsX Sierra and i tried installing connector, mysqlclient and nothing worked for me.

I use PyCharm, and whenever I type

```
import MySQLdb
```

or

```
import mysql.connector
```

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/muhammed/Desktop/PyhtonHomework/venv/homework.py", line 1, in <module>
    import MySQLdb
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb'
```

How can I fix it? I have a term project and i can't even start thanks to this error.

Python version: 3.6.4

Comment: You should post the actual traceback. "Mysql" != "mysql" so the error, as you stated it, doesn't match your code

Comment: I edited the post with traceback.

Comment: It's case-sensitive. You should try `import mysql` instead. The first attempt is obviously wrong but the second attempt, if it throws the same error, is not so clear. You did `pip install` the module, right?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried running 'import mysql' and it still prints the same traceback with ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'.

Comment: Yes i installed every required thing with pip install.

Comment: You may need to `pip3 install` it to ensure it's in Python 3.

Comment: i now installed with pip3 in terminal with dialog: pip3 install mysqlclient
Collecting mysqlclient
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
Successfully installed mysqlclient-1.3.12

Comment: and still the same error :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MySQLdb doesn’t support Python 3. Try using an alternative MySQL Python package.

I successfully used [MySQL Connector Python](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/), specifically http://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/Connector-Python/mysql-connector-python-2.0.4.zip with Python 3 — have a look at the latest version and the usage documentation.

```
pip install http://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/Connector-Python/mysql-connector-python-2.0.4.zip
```

then

```
import mysql.connector
```

Using the latest version available (I believe 2.1.7).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I already tried installing and importing mysql.connector but Pycharm still gives me ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'.

Comment: Can it be caused by the installation path or someting?

Comment: Which package are you trying to install exactly? What command are you running?

Comment: i wrote to terminal: pip install mysql-connector-repackaged and it was installed successfully.

Comment: Please see my edit - it sounds like you need to install a different package.

Comment: I installed it now, same error. I restarted pycharm and even the computer after the installation, but always the same error. I think it is caused by something in file paths. But i don't know why.

Comment: Are you running a virtual environment? If so, are your packages being installed there? Alternatively, try installing the package from PyCharm’s project preferences menu.

Comment: yes, i now searched the packages are under anaconda. /Users/muhammed/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages I dont know if pycharm can reach there though.

Comment: Oh i now tried it spyder, and connector is working. thank you very much. But is there a way to install the package for pycharm also? thanks.

Comment: Click PyCharm > Preferences > Project > Project Interpreter. Select the correct interpreter (ideally use a virtual environment). You can see all your packages installed for the current project here, and press the + to add a new one. Once you're using the correct interpreter, you should be able to `pip install` too.

Comment: Thank you so much alstr. I can start my project now! :)