# Python import MySQLdb on MacOS M1 doesn't work

Tags: python, mysql, macos, mysql-python

I have Python `3.8.8`, `mysql` and `mysql-client` installed. I also have installed both `mysql-connector-python==8.0.26` & `mysqlclient==2.1.0` library using `pip`.

But the line

> python -c "import MySQLdb"

returns this error :

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/louisgabilly/anaconda3/envs/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from . import _mysql
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/louisgabilly/anaconda3/envs/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-38-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _mysql_affected_rows
  Referenced from: /Users/louisgabilly/anaconda3/envs/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-38-darwin.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/louisgabilly/anaconda3/envs/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-38-darwin.so
>
>During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/louisgabilly/anaconda3/envs/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    version_info, _mysql.version_info, _mysql.__file__
NameError: name '_mysql' is not defined
```

I believe this error is due to MacOS M1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good discussion is in https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient/issues/496 and this problem arises that the architecture (ARM64 or Intel) of the Python is not consistent with the architecture of mysqlclient. So, check which python you are using (since you might use some python you are not intended) and the consistence between them

Answer (score 0):

Even though, you have installed `mysqlclient`, you need to install the Oracle native client library for it to work. You can install the client using brew.

```
brew install mysql-client
```

Comment: mysql-client is also already installed using brew

Answer (score 0):

as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49349672/12594882) answer said
MySQLdb doesn’t support Python 3  you should be importing

```py
import mysql.connector
```

Comment: The library I am trying to use https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow/ uses `import MySQLdb`

Comment: can you specify exactly where it says  `import MySQLdb`

Comment: I believe this is the exact line where the error occurs : https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/8a03a505e1df0f9de276038c5509135ac569a667/airflow/settings.py#L366